# Open Android standard keyboard in the app even if a custom keyboard is selected in the device

Tags: android, android-keypad

I want to open Android standard keyboard in my app even if a custom keyboard is installed and selected in the device. Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: So do you just want a yes or no answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

First, there is no "Android standard keyboard". Out of the ~2 billion Android devices and ~10,000 device models, dozens (if not hundreds) of input method editors will be pre-installed.

Second, an app cannot control what input method editor the user wants to use.